# what I need to add in this (.gitlab-ci.yml) file ? It is a flutter project that has runed on gitlab 's CI/CD

Tags: flutter, gitlab, apk

I want to use gitlab's CI for build a apk.I hava try many,but I don't know what I am not doing good.
I can build this apk in my android studio's Termainal.So my project maybe don't hava erro.

<sub>image: cirrusci/flutter:3.7.1</sub>

stages:

- build

cache:
paths:
- .pub-cache/

before_script:

- cd my_app
- export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn
- export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn

build:
stage: build
script:
- flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64  --no-sound-null-safety

These are gitlab's CI report erro:

<sub>Dart 3 will only support sound null safety, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.</sub>

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':archem_idcard'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':archem_idcard:classpath'.
> Could not download kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.4.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.4.1/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar'.
> > Read timed out
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':archem_idcard' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':archem_idcard' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1h 45m 19s

I hava add chinese web mirro:https://pub.flutter-io.cn,https://storage.flutter-io.cn

I hope one good teacher that can help.Please I hava taste 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

First, just make sure the project is assembled, because I see errors during assemblytry this option

```
 image: ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter:latest

stages:
  - buildAPK
  - buildBUNDLE

flutter_build_apk:
  stage: buildAPK
  script:
    - flutter build apk --release 
  artifacts:
    name: "flutterAPK"
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

flutter_build_bundle:
  stage: buildBUNDLE
  script:
    - flutter build appbundle --release 
  artifacts:
    name: "flutterBUNDLE"
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
```

wrote based on an [article](https://medium.com/@roger.tan/setup-a-flutter-ci-cd-with-gitlab-ci-part-3-8e67c91c6da7) when I understood this topic

everything worked in the best possible way
Perhaps someone will answer better, in which case write to me in a telegram @margarin_k_vipechke
Thank you in advance